# Python IDLE less or more?

Tags: python

Getting a list of `__builtins__` in IDLE how do I pause it after a certain number or bottom of the screen?

This gives me one at a time..

```
>>> for i in dir(__builtins__):
...     print i
...     raw_input("Press Enter...")
```

and I could slice it like ...

```
x=dir(__builtins__)
len(x)    
for i in x[:10]:
print i
```

... and that give me first 10 but is there a way to get it to print 10, or bottom of screen until the user input ?  Like a less or more in Unix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
print_every = 5

for i, f in enumerate(dir(__builtins__)):
    print f

    if i % print_every == 0 and i != 0:
        raw_input("Press Enter...")
```

- `enumerate` pairs each entry in the list with its index in the list
- `if i % print_every == 0:` checks to see if `i` (the current index) is a multiple of `print_every`.

The above code should print the list in groups of `print_every` many entries.

Comment: Grazi!!  Many thanks especially for the explanation.

Comment: @JohnRain Note, I actually have the condition wrong. It will only print 1 entry in the first iteration. I'll fix it. Check back in a couple minutes.

Comment: @JohnRain There, it's mostly fix. It will currently print `print_every` + 1 many entries in the first iteration. With some tinkering, I'm sure you'll be able to fix it up.

Comment: works great, perfect for poking around... out of curiousity does it not work in 3.4?

Comment: @JohnRain You'd need to change `print` to a function, and `raw-input` to `input`, but yes it works in 3. I tested it using QPython3. And if this  answer helped you, I'd appreciate an upvote.

Comment: thank you sir!  Dude I'd love to give you an upvote but I don't have the 'reputation' yet.  It says it's recorded it but doesn't show it???  Also, your answer looks a lot simpler, more pythonic, than the ones that Martjin marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnRain Np, that's ok. And the duplicate answer is actually very similar to mine. Note it also uses `enumerate`. The main differences are that theirs allows early exit by inputting "q", while mine loops until the entire list is printed, and that there's works for different lists while mine only loops over `dir(__builtins__)`. I wanted to keep it simple to act as an approachable example. I'm glad this helped you.